# Amazon RDS switch server between Reader instance and Writer instance

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using Amazon Aurora and I have 2 database server by default:
The Reader instance and the Writer instance.

My application is connecting to the primary connection endpoint

`sample.cluster-sample.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com`

However, my application can't write data into the database suddenly and I found the replica (sample-instance-r1) has become Writer instance.

My application is programmed using Node.js with [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) plugin and using connection pool. How can I avoid amazon RDS switch the Writer instance and thus not able to write data?

Comment: Happened with me as well. Did you find a resolution? Is this something AWS support were able to help with?

Comment: @LNI In my experience, I've observed that a high volume of connections and read operations on the RDS can cause the database to malfunction and switch to another replica. If you're experiencing similar issues, it may be worth checking the traffic on your RDS to see if this is the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

The cluster endpoint address [does not change due to failover](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.AuroraHighAvailability.html#Concepts.AuroraHighAvailability.Instances):

> To use a connection string that stays the same even when a failover promotes a new primary instance, you connect to the cluster endpoint. The **cluster endpoint always represents the current primary instance** in the cluster.

So what you are describing does not normally happen when you are using cluster endpoint (not counting the time required for the failover to compete). Thus please make sure that you application is actually using that endpoint as Aurora has [multiple endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Overview.Endpoints.html#Aurora.Overview.Endpoints.Types).

Comment: I am connecting the primary endpoint. I find that the database is failover to another endpoint and thus the origin one has become the read instance but seem that node.js mysql plugin doesn't notice that. I choose to perform health check on the application and restart it if it can't write data into database. I don't think it is a good solution but I have no idea to deal with that.

Comment: @KenYip You must use `cluster endpoint`. Only this endpoint protects against what you are describing.

Comment: I will confirm this answer while technically correct is invalid to answer the question "normally happen" is the problem this has just happened to me and my entire team breaking every setup we have so should not happen but damn well has happened for some strange reason

Comment: @Barkermn01 how did your team resolve your situation?

Comment: @Christian I used the SDK to read the values from RDS AWS API, in my case i used the preload section so above the method that is exported for Lambda

Comment: Not the best way, but we switched back to the original roles by manually failovering the writer instance from the actions of the aws portal